# Multiple nested if statements

Tags: ms-word, field, conditional-statements

I am attempting to write a field conditional that will give two rate factors based on price ranges hte one listed below is on a range of 50k < x < 100k. The issue is that my document is currently presenting a blank cell.  I've attempted to follow the [example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211363), but I still am returning an empty cell. What am I missing here?

```
IF {=AND({COMPARE {MERGEFIELD  Price} >= 5000 },{ COMPARE  {MERGEFIELD  Price} <=100000})} =1 "{= {MERGEFIELD Price} *0.09044}" "n/a" \# C0 \*MERGEFORMAT
```

Comment: (1) I could not access the example file. (2) Let's assume *all* the {} are the special field code braces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word. If not, they need to be. (3) "<=100000" should be "<= 100000" or the result of the second COMPARE will probably be an error. (4) "=1" should be "= 1" (same reason). 5. What is the value inserted by { MERGEFIELD Price } on its own? If it contains a currency symbol, is it the same one as in Windows Regional Settings (assuming this is Windows Word)

Comment: @bibadia 1. Updated link 2. Correct 3&4 adjusted. 6. Just a price in numbers format.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything else wrong with the code (except you obviously need a { } around the whole thing). Most errors should in any case result in "N/A?. Unless you have done something like format the result as white text, in which case the MERGEFORMAT would keep it that way (seems unlikely though). Always worth selecting the lot and re-executing the fields. Does it behave any differently if you copy/paste or reconstruct outside a table? (No difference here, BTW).

Comment: @Thanks. The n/a was it.

Comment: Glad it's sorted. I'm still a bit mystified as to what exactly sorted it, but there you go. Can you close the similar question you posted on Answers?